# Floating multi-line fieldsets

Tags: html, css, fieldset

I have a fieldset markup with multiple fieldsets. Inside the container they are floating and create a form together.
[image]

Without any 'hacks' my fieldsets are not floating because they are block elements and therefor are aligned below each other. Right now I'm using a negative margin to get my 2nd fieldset up next to the last element of fieldset 1.
This is kinda hacky imo and is pretty annoying if you have several fieldsets and other forms which are a little bit different. Means I have to duplicate some css code and override it instead of having a fluidly floating form.

Is there any possibility to have the last element of fieldset 1 and the first item of fieldset 2 floating appropriately?

E: I created a small fiddle for the inline-block proposuals - not working for me in chrome: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sty7gbnh/)

```
<fieldset>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <input type="text" />
</fieldset>

fieldset {
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: `display:inline-block`?

Comment: actually this isn't working, at least in chrome. the fieldsets are still appearing as block elements, most likely due to some browser restrictions?

Comment: If you want the fieldset to appear inside the other fieldset, try putting it... inside the fieldset!

Comment: which is not possible that's why I'm asking for a css solution in case there is one. Fieldsets are being created by zend framework and produce unique params therefor I can't touch those fieldsets.

Comment: I'm just happy you decided to create a jsfiddle for me to actually work with.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure fieldset1 and fieldset2's container is set as `display: inline-block;` and the fields themselves are also set as `display: inline-block;`

This will ensure that they aren't entirely blocks that will clear and set the other elements on to a new line.

Also, remove any floating since you can achieve what you want without floating. Floating will only complicate things at this point.

---

**EDIT** ------> Based on your jsfiddle, here is an updated one: http://jsfiddle.net/sty7gbnh/1/

There are margins/paddings around your fieldset. While you have set them as inline-blocks, you need to remove their initial margins/paddings still. For example, buildings (which would be fieldsets) with a margin of 5cm on each side will create a 10cm gap between each building... giving you that awkward space.

---

**EDIT** ------> Upon further inspection, I'm unsure as to how we can achieve this with just css and can only suggest using jquery:

```
fs = $("fieldset");
for (i = 0; i < fs.length; i++) {
    var that = $(fs[i]);
    var fieldsetContent = that.html();
    that.replaceWith(''+fieldsetContent+'');
};
```

The above code will replace all field sets with nothing (therefore removing fieldsets) and leaving just the input fields alone. This could be edited to target a specific area/container.

Comment: this isn't working, have already tried this in my code. see my edit - I added a really simple fiddle and the inline block element still appears to be a block element.

Comment: I fixed your sample with a new updated jsfiddle in my answer. Take a look, an explanation was provided.

Comment: in your fiddle the fieldset 2 is still below fieldset 1 even tho there is enough space to float next to the last element..

Comment: Actually, I don't see how it's below. Are you sure your screen just isn't big enough? I've attached an image of what I'm seeing (in all browsers)

Comment: Ah, I see it now, it's when you shrink it. Let me see if i can come up with a solution.

Comment: In the end, I suppose I can only offer you js as a solution. Sorry.

Comment: thanks for your effort - upvote for that but I can't mark the question as resolve - most likely it's not possible to archive what I want without any css hacks so i will just keep them.